# Can I extend the dates of my already given Schengen visa?

Tags: visas, schengen

I have a Schengen visa given by the Norwegian embassy of 14 days from 8 Feb to 8 March. An urgent matter came up and I have to go to Denmark on 3-4 feb. Keeping in mind that I only have around 10 days, what will be the best possible solution?

Cancel the previous visa and apply a new one from the Denmark embassy? 
Or ask the Norwegian embassy to extend my visa?

Comment: Are you planning two separate trips, one to Denmark followed by a second one to Norway, or one trip combining the two?

Answer (score 4):

Since your new trip lies completely outside the validity period of your existing visa, you would just apply for a visa for that from the Danish consulate separately.

It is commonly said that you can't have two Schengen visas, but that inaccurate. What is true is just that consulates are not supposed to issue visas *that overlap in validity* with an already issued visa.

It won't hurt to explain the relation (or lack of same) to the Norway visa when you apply anew, and state that you still plan to go on that trip too.